# How to use GstReferenceTimestampMeta properly

Tags: c++, gstreamer

My goal is to attach timestamps to `GstBuffer` which is independent of GST time. I found [GstReferenceTimestampMeta](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstbuffer.html?gi-language=c#GstReferenceTimestampMeta), which looks exactly what I am after. However I have some issues when trying to utilize it. Maybe I have misundestood the usage of the GstMeta structure.

Brief overview of pipeline:

server: `appsrc -> h265enc -> rtp -> udpsink`

client: `udpsrc -> h265decode -> appsink`

What I am doing in the server is to attach the `GstMeta` to a `GstBuffer` before pushing the buffer into the `appsrc`, as such:

```cpp
auto buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, buffer_size, NULL);

// ------------------------- GstReferenceTimestampMeta START

GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_from_string("timestamp/x-test-stream");
gst_buffer_add_reference_timestamp_meta(
  buffer,
  caps,
  timestamp.nanoseconds(),
  GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE 
);  

// ------------------------- GstReferenceTimestampMeta END
    
GstMapInfo info;
gst_buffer_map(buffer, &info, GST_MAP_READ);
std::memcpy(info.data, image.data, buffer_size);
gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &info);
gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc_), buffer);
```

Similarly, what I do at the client side is:

```cpp
GstSample *sample = gst_app_sink_try_pull_sample(GST_APP_SINK(appsink_), 10000000);
GstBuffer *buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);

// ------------------------- GstReferenceTimestampMeta START

GstReferenceTimestampMeta *meta;
GstCaps *reference = gst_caps_from_string("timestamp/x-test-stream");
meta = gst_buffer_get_reference_timestamp_meta(buffer, reference);
if (meta == NULL){
  std::cout << "daim" << std::endl;   
  break;
}
else {
  std::cout << meta->timestamp << std::endl; 
}

// ------------------------- GstReferenceTimestampMeta END

MapInfo buffer_mapping;
gst_buffer_map(buffer, &buffer_mapping, GST_MAP_READ);
GstCaps *caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);

GstStructure *properties = gst_caps_get_structure(caps, 0);

int width, height;
gst_structure_get_int(properties, "width", &width);
gst_structure_get_int(properties, "height", &height);
std::string format = gst_structure_get_string(properties, "format");

int numChannels = (format == "BGR") ? 3 : 1;

renderTracks(buffer_mapping.data, width, height, numChannels);

loadBufferOnDevice(width, height, numChannels, buffer_mapping.data);

gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &buffer_mapping);
gst_sample_unref(sample);
```

The result here is "daim" printed to cout as the `GstMeta` with reference caps "timestamp/x-test-stream" is not found, and thus the variable `meta == NULL`.

I might have misundestood the usage of the GstMeta structure. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. If there are other methods of attaching "custom" timestamp to a buffer, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know, GstMeta data is intra-pipeline only. If you need an inter-pipeline solution, you need to implement it in the coded (H.264, H.265, ...) or in the RTP header.

Cheers,